# A horror movie that turns out to be a prank

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I've seen this horror movie one or two years ago. Recent american production.

It starts with a group of friends starting some **game show** (same concept of the Hunger Games) somewhere in a huge closed place (somewhere creepy), they (some machines probably)  will give them instructions what to do.

Each person gets assigned to do something. It was scary.

Later, a black male gets stuck in some hole, and murderers were all over the place, it was real, creepy they started fighting and running away from them.

Since it's a game show, the producers (or managers) were watching everything on the screen and enjoying it. They were criminals enjoying the show.

At the end, some girl (producer or creator) shows and she starts clapping her hands, along with the crew. It was all a prank (it leaves the watcher surprised, because it's was a huge plot twist).

The murderers were actors.

It turns out also that at the end, a real mentally-ill psychopath was there, not inside the crew, he took the life of a girl (who got locked in a room in a chair and suffocated).

Anyone who could identity this horror movie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like [The Task](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Task_%28film%29) from 2011. From [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1621446/combined):

> Something diabolical is taking place on the set of "The Task" a new reality show in which players complete terrifying missions within the confines of an abandoned prison hoping to win a hefty cash prize. As six young students explore their new environment, malicious spirits make their presence known in the most gruesome ways imaginable, Unable to escape the labyrinthine prison, the contestants become unwitting pawns caught at the centre of a blood-soaked night of terror.

One of the contestant (a black male) is stuck in a hole and another one (a woman) is strapped to a chair in a gas chamber. In the end, the whole thing turns out to be a prank on the show's producer - but in another twist, the evil entity in the jail turns out to be real, and some of the people did die (including the woman gassed in the chair). Here's the trailer: